# How to pass data from a class to an activity

Tags: java, android

I have a viewpager with a card layout and want to send the position of the page a user has clicked to open a specific acvity. I want to send the position to my activity from a adapter class but I am receiving an **error of null pointer exception.**

I have tried using handler and a custom Interface in these code.

My custom Interface

```
package com.example.authentication.Interface;

public interface MyCustomInterface {
    public void sendData (int pos);
}
```

My sendData function in Activity

```
@Override
public void sendData(final int pos) {

    Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(pos));

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

My Adapter class onClickListener

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //this will log the page number that was click
            Log.i("TAG", "This page was clicked: " + position);
            myCustomInterface.sendData(position);
        }
    });
```

**ERROR**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.example.authentication.Interface.MyCustomInterface.sendData(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.example.authentication.ListAdapter$1.onClick(ListAdapter.java:63)

Comment: you just use intent to pass data, interface is not necessary

Comment: you likely set `myCustomInterface` incorrectly, or don't set it at all. Show how you set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter class add this :

```
private MyCustomInterface mCustomInterface;
```

Then in the adpater constructor in adapter class :

```
public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<SomeData> data, mCustomInterface) {
this.context=context;    
this.mCustomInterface= mCustomInterface;
this.dataSet = data;
}
```

Then in your activity class when creating instance of your adapter :

```
MyAdapter mAdapter= new MyAdapter(context,data, new MyCustomInterface() {
                @Override
                public void sendData (int position) {

                   //do whatever you want here  
                }

            });
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 0):

1. Implements  the interface in your activity
2. Pass the interface object to Adapter using the constructor.

MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,list,this);

Now in Adapter class
Use the constructor as discussed above by Ahmad.
public MyAdapter(Context ctx, List<> list,MyCustomInterface interface){

}

3.use the listener object to call the interface function
interface.sendData(position);

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you have a viewpager and you want to send the position that has been clicked to another activity , right?
this way you can use `SharedPreferences` in this way that you save the position in a the sharedpreferance and you use it later in the any activity , in sendData add :

```
SharedPreferences pref;
      switch (pos) {

                case 0: 
            pref=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("POS",0);
            editor.commit();
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
            pref=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("POS",1);
            editor.commit();
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
            pref=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("POS",0);
            editor.commit();
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
            pref=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("POS",0);
            editor.commit();
                    intent.putExtra("Code", "MN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
```

And then , in any activity you want add:

```
        SharedPreferences prefs=getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int i=prefs.getInt("POS",1);
```

and use 'i' however you want...